# Make editable element overflow to new element

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have an editable element `contentarea-block` where I'd like to set the max-width and height to 8.5in x 11 in which I have been able to do just fine of course.  What I'm struggling with is once the height for the container `contentarea-page` exceeds 1056 pixels (11in) then I want to create another editable page right after and have the overflow content on that page.

For context: (updated) For context, we're creating a proposal builder and as content is added, edited, removed from a page, if the page exceeds the set height it creates a new page.  If someone removes content from a "page" it removes the empty "page".  Think Microsoft Word as @Roko pointed out in the comments.

I created a fiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/8qzwm9kL/ to show where my issues are.  Currently, it's not working 100%, for example, if I keep hitting enter or typing random stuff on new lines, sometimes it creates several empty pages instead of just one immediately following the overflowed element.  Secondly, it doesn't automatically move my cursor onto the new page for a fluid transition of editing between pages.

Any help would be appreciated.  I'm not even sure what to search for on SO or Google :)

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  var docHeight = 1056; //11in
  var docWidth = 816; //8.5in

  //$('.contentarea-block').width(docWidth).height(docHeight);

  $('.contentarea-block').each(function() {
    console.log($(this).innerHeight());
    $(this).bind("change keyup input", function() {
      if ($(this).innerHeight() >= docHeight) {
        $(this).after('<div class="contentarea-page"><div class="contentarea-block container is-container"><div class="row clearfix"><div class="column full"><div class="display"><p class="size-18 " style="text-transform: uppercase;">Drag and Drop Proposal Builder</p> <h1 class="size-50">Add or Remove Blocks to Get Started</h1></div></div></div></div></div>');
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.contentarea-page {
  height: 1056px;
  max-height: 1056px;
  width: 816px;
  background: #ccc;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.contentarea-block {
  background: #efefef;
}
```

```html
<div class="contentarea-page">
  <div id="contentarea" class="contentarea-block container is-container" contenteditable="true">
    <div class="row clearfix">
      <div class="column full">
        <div class="display">
          <p class="size-18 " style="text-transform: uppercase;">Drag and Drop Proposal Builder</p>
          <h1 class="size-50">Add or Remove Blocks to Get Started</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: may I ask why those strict width/height values? Letter size? PS, A4 = 8.27 x 11.69"  We're in a responsive era, and seeing a layout based on px or in is quite odd. Also, not sure to know what to do to reproduce your issue. What are you building?

Comment: Have you ever used `::after`? I haven't tested it myself but it is where I'd start. 

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Note that copying work from an external site to this one is relicensing their work under a likely different license. OPs should be doing that work themselves if they are willing to have their work relicensed.

Comment: Note that `bind` has been deprecated for a while; use `on` instead. Also, you don't need `each`, so you can just do `$('.contentarea-block').on("change keyup input", ...)` Even better might be `$(document).on("change keyup input", '.contentarea-block', ...)` so that the event handlers apply to those yet-to-be-created elements.

Comment: I'm not sure if it would be helpful in terms of replicating the issue but I'm happy to do a short video or try to offer more explanation on it.  I know it's hard to explain but we're pretty much building an internal proposal builder.  So the builder allows users to create "pages" and ideally as they're adding content to the "page" element, it will automatically add the next page once the height for the div is reached and then the cursor/overflowed content falls to the next "page".

Comment: @HereticMonkey thank you for the reminder - I always forget about SO's *cc by-sa* vs. jsFiddle's (*arr*, or as defined) Hopefully a couple of DIV elements with a partial jQuery are by no means copyright infringement - specially if a posted answer would include the same/similar. Sorry Derek ;)

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan this is for a proposal builder, the reason we have the strict height/width is because we are using JSPDF package and when someone goes to print the proposal it formats on the pages correctly because ideally the editor was set up to respect those print sizes

Comment: So basically like Word? Add more content and you got more pages, Remove content and the extra empty pages are gone?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan exactly! Thank you for mentioning that, that's exactly what I'm going for in my end result

Comment: @Derek humm... that's quite a pain to do. HTML formatting, tags splitting.... quite a complicated job - specially given all the quirks of `contenteditable`

Comment: Someone doesn't have to do the work for me, I'm just looking for general direction based on where I'm at now.  Currently with my code it creates several cloned "pages" so I'm not doing something correctly.

Comment: Hopefully my answer can help get you a little farther, @Derek. It won't solve all the problems (if you go back to the now-just-long-enough element and add some more text, it will create yet another "page" and send focus there, as an example), but you can tweak the code for those kinds of things (maybe remove the `contenteditable` attribute so a user can't edit previous pages, or add `function (e) { e.preventDefault(); ` to the handler so the user can't type any more. Those decisions have to be made as part of a larger design decision and really expand the scope of this question too much.

Answer (score 1):

The key is to ensure the new element is editable, and to set the focus on the newly added element. Right now, the code just adds the element (without `contenteditable="true"`) every time the currently focused editable element is equal to or greater in height than your maximum.

In this code, it adds the new element, finds the editable element, and sets the focus.

The `$(document).on("change keyup input", '.contentarea-block', function()` bit makes sure the event handler runs for any element with the class `contentarea-block` that exists, *or will exist* in the DOM.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  var docHeight = 1056; //11in
  var docWidth = 816; //8.5in

  //$('.contentarea-block').width(docWidth).height(docHeight);

  $(document).on("change keyup input", '.contentarea-block', function() {
    if ($(this).innerHeight() >= docHeight) {
      $(this).after('<div class="contentarea-page"><div class="contentarea-block container is-container" contenteditable="true"><div class="row clearfix"><div class="column full"><div class="display"><p class="size-18 " style="text-transform: uppercase;">Drag and Drop Proposal Builder</p> <h1 class="size-50">Add or Remove Blocks to Get Started</h1></div></div></div></div></div>');
      $(this).next(".contentarea-page").find(".contentarea-block").focus();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.contentarea-page {
  height: 1056px;
  max-height: 1056px;
  width: 816px;
  background: #ccc;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.contentarea-block {
  background: #efefef;
}
```

```html
<div class="contentarea-page">
  <div id="contentarea" class="contentarea-block container is-container" contenteditable="true">
    <div class="row clearfix">
      <div class="column full">
        <div class="display">
          <p class="size-18 " style="text-transform: uppercase;">Drag and Drop Proposal Builder</p>
          <h1 class="size-50">Add or Remove Blocks to Get Started</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Removing stuff does not work. Editing means adding and removing.